# mysql update a column from another column's serialized key value

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql column called `"_ait-item_item-data"` with value like this

```
a:30:{s:8:"subtitle";s:0:"";s:12:"featuredItem";s:1:"1";s:10:"headerType";s:3:"map";s:11:"headerImage";s:0:"";s:16:"headerImageAlign";s:0:"";s:3:"map";a:7:{s:7:"address";s:43:"527 2nd Avenue, South Charleston, WV, 25303";s:8:"latitude";d:38.36640390000000166992322192527353763580322265625;s:9:"longitude";d:-81.688525499999997236955096013844013214111328125;s:10:"streetview";i:1;s:9:"swheading";s:0:"";s:7:"swpitch";s:0:"";s:6:"swzoom";s:0:"";}s:9:"telephone";s:0:"";s:19:"telephoneAdditional";s:0:"";s:5:"email";s:0:"";s:9:"showEmail";s:1:"1";s:15:"contactOwnerBtn";s:1:"1";s:3:"web";s:68:"http://pyramidcounselingllc.com/south-charleston-wv-location/5100852";s:12:"webLinkLabel";s:0:"";}
```

I want to update 2 other mysql columns, `"ait-latitude"` and `"ait-longitude"`  using the longitude & laitutde from the above serialized value

I know a mysql query for standard type of columns will be like

```
UPDATE table SET ait-latitude = _ait-item_item-data WHERE id = 1
```

I just can not get my head around how to fetch value from serialized array though.

Comment: Well, you have this question tagged as PHP, so have you considered fetching the data, using PHP to extract the part you want, and then using that in an update statement?

Comment: I am sorry, that php tag was added mistakenly. I don't want to involve Php .. just mysql query will be fine as there are over 40 thousand records that I have to deal here.

Comment: Sorry, but you can't do it like that.

Comment: This looks like PHP serialized data which is basically meaningless to MySQL. You need PHP to decode that. If this had been stored as JSON you would be able to use MySQL 5.7 functions to extract what you need.

Comment: what data type  is `"_ait-item_item-data" ` ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza The data sample value is given above for _ait-item_item-data

Comment: data sample doesnt say what type is. Is a string?

Comment: So mysql doesn't have an array type so you cannot fetch a value from a serialized array using MySQL alone. For that you will need PHP (and will have to add the PHP tag back in :)). https://99webtools.com/blog/how-to-store-array-in-mysql/

Comment: ok guys, so there is really no way to fetch the information from that value using mysql query .. guess I have to move to php ( which sucks by the way ).

Comment: Or you can design your db properly instead :p .  .... You know one field for each property

Comment: I wish I could .. I inherited this db with 40k records.. not fun